# Difference between VARX and ADL models

Tags: time-series, econometrics

Could anyone please elucidate the difference between `Vector Autoregressive Models with exogenous variables, VARX(p,q`) and `autoregressive distributed lag models ADL(p,q)`? Based on the descriptions of two models, they appear to be the same so why different names are given?

Answer (score 4):

VARX(p,q) is not a standard notation. VARX usually means VAR with exogenous variables, i.e.

$$Y_t=A_0+A_1Y_{t-1}+...+A_pY_{t-p}+DX_t+\varepsilon_t$$

where $Y_t,X_t,\varepsilon_t$ are **vectors** and $A_0,...,A_p,D$ are matrices. Whereas ADL(p,q) is usually understood as the following model

$$y_t=a_0+a_1y_{t-1}+...+a_py_{t-p}+b_1x_{t-1}+...+b_qx_{t-q}+\varepsilon_t,$$

where $y_t,x_t,\varepsilon_t$ are **scalar** variables and $a_0,...,a_p,b_1,...,b_q$ are scalar coefficients.

It is not hard to see that ADL(p,q) is a special case of VARX(p) model. So they are definitely not the same model.

The ADL(p,q) model historically was important in causality testing (not only of course). Nobel prize winner [Christopher A. Sims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_A._Sims) used this model in his famous article "[Money, Income and Causality](http://www.jstor.org/sici?sici=0002-8282%28197209%2962:4%3C540%3aMIAC%3E2.0.CO;2-#&)". Furthermore there is a lot of literature devoted to models where coefficients of ADL(p,q) model are restricted, i.e. they are generated by some non-linear function. There is a little overview in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koyck_lag#Infinite_distributed_lags).

Comment: to mpiktas:but the links you provide for christopher and ADL(p,q) do not represent the linkage of author with model